# Getting XMLHttpRequest erros on ajax Post

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a modal in which there's a form that I want users to be able to submit an email with. I set up the ajax post like I usually would, however, the post keeps failing. When it does, I get the following two errors in the console.

> 1. Setting XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials for synchronous requests is deprecated
> 2. Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.

Interestingly, the email sometimes sends regardless of the errors, but sometimes it doesn't either.

Here is my Html:

```
<form class="cmxform" id="contactForm" >
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">    

                <label class="col-md-12 control-label" style="text-align: left;" >Name</label>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input required class="form-control" id="FromName" name="FromName" style="margin-bottom: 10px;" type="text" value=""/>
                </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">

                <label class="col-md-12 control-label" style="text-align: left;" >Email</label>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input required class="form-control" style="margin-bottom: 10px;" id="FromEmail" name="FromEmail" type="text" value=""/>
                </div>

        </div>

    </div>

        <label class="col-md-12 control-label" >Message</label>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <textarea required class="form-control contact-message" cols="20"  id="Message" name="Message" rows="2"></textarea>

        </div>


    <div class="col-md-12">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
    </div>


</form>
```

And my JS:

```
function sendMessage(messageData) {

    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        url: '/api/SendMessageApi',
        type: 'POST',
        data: messageData,
        success: function () {

        },
        error: function (ex) {
            alert('there was an error');
        }
    });
}


$("#contactForm").submit(function () {

    var name = $('#FromName').val();
    var email = $('#FromEmail').val();
    var message = $('#Message').val();

    var messageData = { Name: name, Email: email, Message: message };

    sendMessage(messageData); 
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You have to prevent the submit event on the form in order to get your ajax request a chance to complete

Comment: I'm game to give it a shot! Is that a tricky thing to accomplish?

Comment: OK, I tried removing type='submit' from my submit button and changing the js method to a click event and it seems to be working. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way that I delay the submit event until after the ajax call is finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To submit the `form` after ajax success, you can use:

```
function sendMessage(messageData) {

    $.ajax({
        context: this, // set context to the form
        async: true,
        url: '/api/SendMessageApi',
        type: 'POST',
        data: messageData,
        success: function () {
            this.submit(); // submit form on success
        },
        error: function (ex) {
            alert('there was an error');
        }
    });
}


$("#contactForm").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $('#FromName').val();
    var email = $('#FromEmail').val();
    var message = $('#Message').val();

    var messageData = { Name: name, Email: email, Message: message };

    sendMessage.call(this, messageData); // set context to the form
});
```